# Read only first level directories javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read all the directories in a given directory which is selected by the user using:

```
<input type="file" id="directory-chooser" webkitdirectory directory/>
```

Once the user has selected the desired folder. I am able to fetch all the files using:

```
var files = document.getElementById('directory-chooser').files;
console.log(files);
```

The output of this is in the form of:

```
2: File
   lastModifiedDate: Mon Jun 17 2013 17:55:45 GMT+0100 (BST)
   name: "."
   size: 68
   type: ""
   webkitRelativePath: "Movies/Superman returns/."
   length: 3
```

As it can be seen, on selecting the directory named `Movies`, I get the list of all "files" in it. However, I simply want it to stop looking into the sub-directories and return `Superman returns` as a result. Though I want it to keep looking for more first level directories, if there are any.

Comment: jquery tag is unrelated.

Comment: maybe you can split the strings by "/" symbol

Comment: @Edorka - That is one way, but that will lead to unnecessary duplications (i.e. if it has multiple files in the folder) and then will require to filter out duplicate results. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I don't see any attribute which can restrict recursion depth, also I don't see any specification of directory attribute. It looks like there is no way.

Comment: Which browser are you using this in? Chrome? Which version? This doesn't run the same in all browsers right?

Comment: @meewoK, yes it works only on Chrome at the moment. I am using version 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of "/" inside the path of each file. If the user selects a folder "foo", the paths of the returned files will be:

```
foo/bar.txt
foo/bar/baz.txt
(...)
```

Thus, you only want the files that have one forward slash (i.e. they're directly under the selected directory, not in a subdirectory).

Here's the HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="directory-chooser" webkitdirectory directory/>
<input type="button" value="files" onclick="showFiles()">
```

and here's the JS code:

```
function showFiles() {
  var files = document.getElementById('directory-chooser').files;
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].webkitRelativePath.match(/\//g).length == 1) {
            // The file in question is not in a subfolder, so show it
            console.log(files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's a working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BHSDa/

Comment: The main issue with whole concept that recursion depth seems indefinite for me. So I can select drive C: and send my browser into permanent down. Additionally, I can't find any way to define depth manually. I think this is what OP asking.

Comment: That is true, but I can't find any way of specifying the depth in the webkitdirectory docs

Comment: Here is a small optimization: http://jsfiddle.net/78GXA/1/ . As a breadth first tree/folder traversal is used to generate the list of files , a return can be executed when you are deeper than 1 folder. In this way you do not need to make the comparison for all files deeper than the root level. Unfortunately, as the Chrome code itself prepares the list of files there is no way to stop/preempt chrome from crashing when you select a giant directory. Unless there was a flag to specify depth but as Filippos said no such option in API currently.